# Shibboleth not setting attributes after expiration

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I'm using Shibboleth as the SP in my SAML authentication for my asp.net application. The Idp authenticates the user and sends the response to shibboleth which sets http request variables for each of the attributes returned from the Idp.

The logs below show two authentication requests.  The first one I can see the attributes being sent correctly, but the second one have none of the attributes being sent.  The attributes are normally sent in the xml response from the idp in a "saml:AttributeStatement" node, but this does not appear in the second request. The warn log below shows this as well.

Why would these attributes not be sent from the Idp on the second request?

Is there anything else I can look for in the config/logs?

I have not been able to recreate the issue consistently yet.  I have tried to wait until after Shibboleth has removed it's cached response (i think it caches the response from the idp?), but sometimes the Idp returns back the attribute node and sometimes not.

```
Warn log:
2014-07-29 09:37:11 WARN Shibboleth.AttributeResolver.Query [32]: no SAML 2 AttributeAuthority role found in metadata

Shibd Log:
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [32]: new session created: ID (_4a08732fafc683618ec84f743679a558) IdP (https://<idp url>) Protocol(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) Address (<client ip>)
2014-07-29 09:37:10 INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [32]: removed session (_4a08732fafc683618ec84f743679a558)
2014-07-29 09:37:11 WARN Shibboleth.AttributeResolver.Query [32]: no SAML 2 AttributeAuthority role found in metadata
2014-07-29 09:37:11 INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [32]: new session created: ID (_ebfc98924b1bafc96a646a9e0ef97cd8) IdP (https://<idp url>) Protocol(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) Address (10.60.112.1)
2014-07-29 09:37:12 INFO XMLTooling.StorageService : purged 8 expired record(s) from storage

Transaction Log:
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]: New session (ID: _4a08732fafc683618ec84f743679a558) with (applicationId: default) for principal from (IdP: https://<idp url>) at (ClientAddress: <client ip>) with (NameIdentifier: test@testdomain.com) using (Protocol: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) from (AssertionID: id-eyHUtkCazAdXC6cMPibbv8YhuYc-)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]: Cached the following attributes with session (ID: _4a08732fafc683618ec84f743679a558) for (applicationId: default) {
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   username (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   userGUID (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   lastname (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   role (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   firstname (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   companyName (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   companyGUID (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   emailAddress (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:29:39 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]: }
2014-07-29 09:37:11 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]: New session (ID: _ebfc98924b1bafc96a646a9e0ef97cd8) with (applicationId: default) for principal from (IdP: https://<idp url>) at (ClientAddress: <client ip>) with (NameIdentifier: test@testdomain.com) using (Protocol: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) from (AssertionID: id-jAnsCQo6-BH2skcHhzj8i63jKxQ-)
2014-07-29 09:37:11 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]: Cached the following attributes with session (ID: _ebfc98924b1bafc96a646a9e0ef97cd8) for (applicationId: default) {
2014-07-29 09:37:11 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]:   emailAddress (1 values)
2014-07-29 09:37:11 INFO Shibboleth-TRANSACTION [32]: }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you get your user attributes from a remote system of some sort (OpenLDAP, ...), try to check your network connection. The non-reproducibility might be an indicator of network issues or downtimes of the remote system (e.g. restarts).

Note that Shibboleth uses a connection pool for retrieving user attributes, thus a connection can already be broken before the request is handled.

Regarding the AttributeResolver.Query warning, can you be sure that the metadata for the IdP is available on the SP? Do you use the same IdP and SP for both login attempts? Is the user the same?